# Fetch not working for HTTP request (mobile client - React Native and server - Java)

Tags: react-native

I am working on a cross-platform app using React-Native and fetch is not working for my post request (the request doesn't even arrive at the server).

I get TypeError: Network request failed everytime.

I am using http (not https). There is no problem with the server (I used a rest client and I am able to get an answer from the server)

I tried the followings:

- added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my AndroidManifest.xml
- added network_security_config.xml in my res/xml directory and used android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" to get those configurations in < application.... /> in my AndroidManifest.xml file

I have this in android/build.gradle:

```
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
```

I must add that fetch is working with a mockapi.io for example.

Help, pretty please :)

Answer (score 0):

*HTTPS, **Not** HTTP*

The internet was built on HTTP, but mobile platforms enforce HTTPS requirements with modern encryption and trusted signed certificates. A mobile backend needs to use HTTPS for every endpoint.

link to article:https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-build-restful-api-mobile-app

When you are testing it on mockapi.io uses one or both of the workarounds which will be a real pain if tried to do them in a real world application deployment.

Anyway here are the two main ways to do so:

- Built-in proxy
- Interceptor

Comment: I few weeks ago I managed to make fetch work for http request using the same server, but unfortunately I lost that project and started another one from scratch. I won't upload my app to the store or something, and that's why I wanted to keep it simple(I am only testing it on my localhost). I have seen a lot of people who managed to make it work just by adding the android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and I wanted to know what am I doing wrong.